# problemas com variaveis de ambiente em c++

Tags: c, c++

estou tentando criar uma **variável de ambiente** no Windows usando o **C++**, mas a variável só existe no programa executado.
existe alguma forma de eu criar um **variável de ambiente** global usando o **C++**?

este é o codigo atual:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <direct.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setenv("VARIABLE", "1234", 0);
    cout << getenv("VARIABLE") << endl;
}
```

como disse, o código acima consegue criar um **variável de ambiente**, mas a variável só existe no programa, mas eu preciso que a variável seja acessada por outros programas, tem algum jeito que dê para criar um variável global que possa ser acessada por outros programas em C++? (precisa ser em C++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mudança no ambiente é válida para o processo e os subprocessos apenas.

Altere no registro do Windows usando a API e acessando

```
Computador\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment.
```

De qualquer forma essa alteração não é imediata e pode não acontecer para alguns programas e especialmente serviços até a sessão ser reiniciada. Ou a máquina, claro.

Aumenta o alcance da alteração se enviar a mensagem `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` para as janelas abertas.

[A função na documentação em português](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions)

Claro que o programa tem que rodar com privilégios administrativos e ser testado com cuidado... Não vai gostar disso em loop.

Pode usar qualquer linguagem que tenha acesso a isso. Em C ou C++ é trivial: apenas chame `RegCreateExA` por exemplo